# Can't get to install 'intl' extension for php on debian

Tags: php, debian, pecl, intl

I have a Debian server and I want to install the `intl` extension through `pecl`.

During the installation it asks me:

> "Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :"

Here I've been trying several options, including leaving it empty to use DEFAULT, but I get the following error:

> configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check See
> 'config.log' for more details. ERROR: '/tmp/pear/temp/intl/configure
> --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed

I've installed php5.3 with: `make && make install`.
I have already installed `icu`, but unlike php5.3, it was installed with `apt-get` (i don't know if this is important).

Any idea?

Comment: I wonder if the ICU path question is a distraction; what does config.log contain?

Answer (score 41):

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, the following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Bam, warning gone! Hope this helps somebody in the future :)

Comment: simplest answer, spot on.  UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 21):

You need to install libicu44 and libicu-dev:

```
apt-get install libicu44 libicu-dev
```

and after this you can install intl with pecl:

```
./pecl install intl
```

---

Note if using Ubuntu:

It lLooks like the first package `libicu44` is not available, in which case just install `libicu-dev` and it will go through the dependencies and handle it for you. Seems to use `libicu42` at the moment.

Comment: `aptitude -y install libicu-dev` is enough and will handle the `libicu*` dependency.

Answer (score 11):

Same error:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/collator/collator_class.c:92: error: duplicate 'static'
```

But when reading the intl native extension comments, I saw:

> Debian Squeeze users can install the intl extension with:
>
> sudo apt-get install php5-intl

[first comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php)

The package works even with my old Ubuntu 8.04...

Answer (score 2):

Installing g++ `sudo apt-get install g++`  before `sudo ./pecl install intl` did the trick for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure installing `php5-dev` will solve this issue too. On Ubuntu 14.04 I ran `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`. IIRC this package contained g++

Answer (score 1):

I knew this sounded familiar; I had the same problem back in May 2008, discussed here:
  http://old.nabble.com/ubuntu-7.10-pecl-install-intl-p17140873.html

Ed Batutis explained that "/usr" is the correct answer if you have icu-config at "/usr/bin/icu-config"; adjust accordingly if it is somewhere else.

However that didn't help for me. I described the solution for me here:
  http://darrendev.blogspot.com/2008/05/install-php-pecl-intl-module-for-ubuntu.html
...which was basically to define the PHP_SETUP_ICU macro. That was supposed to be added in 5.2.4, so as you are using php 5.3 your problem ought to be something else.

Comment: Answering `/usr` worked for me after installing `libicu-dev` via `apt-get`