# ICU compiler not found or not working for PHP intl extension

Tags: php, linux, symfony, icu, intl

I am trying to install the intl PHP extension for Symfony 2. To install it I need to provide the path to the ICU binaries. I have downloaded and installed ICU on my VM but when I run the configuring for Linux I get:

checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for definition of U_INLINE for C... **inline**
checking if we have a C++ compiler... no
configure: error: C++ compiler g++ does not work or no compiler found
./runConfigureICU: ./configure failed

If I type in help when running the configuration I get:

Usage: runConfigureICU [ -h, --help ]  [ --enable-debug | --disable-release ] platform [ configurearg ... ]

Options: -h, --help         Print this message and exit
         --enable-debug     Enable support for debugging
         --disable-release  Disable presetting optimization flags

The following names can be supplied as the argument for platform:

```
AIX                 Use the IBM Visual Age xlc_r/xlC_r compilers on AIX
AIX/GCC             Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on AIX
Cygwin              Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on Cygwin
Cygwin/MSVC         Use the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler on Cygwin
Cygwin/MSVC2005     Use the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 compiler on Cygwin
Cygwin/ICL          Use the Intel C++ compiler on Cygwin
FreeBSD             Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on Free BSD
HP-UX/ACC           Use the HP ANSI C/Advanced C++ compilers on HP-UX 11
IBMi                Use the iCC compilers on IBM i, i5/OS, OS/400
Linux               Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on Linux
Linux/ECC           Use the Intel ECC compiler on Linux
Linux/ICC           Use the Intel ICC compiler on Linux
Linux/VA            Use the IBM Visual Age compiler on Power PC Linux
MacOSX              Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on MacOS X (Darwin)
MinGW               Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on MinGW
QNX                 Use the QNX QCC compiler on QNX/Neutrino
Solaris             Use the Sun cc/CC compilers on Solaris
Solaris/GCC         Use the GNU gcc/g++ compilers on Solaris
SolarisX86          Use the Sun cc/CC compilers on Solaris x86
TRU64V5.1/CXX       Use the Compaq cxx compiler on Tru64 (OSF)
zOS                 Use the IBM cxx compiler on z/OS (os/390)
zOSV1R2             Use the IBM cxx compiler for z/OS 1.2
```

I tryed Linux and I have gcc installed. Why is it saying that I do not have a compiler?

I am following this tutorial:
http://www.phamviet.net/2013/01/28/php-54-install-php-intl-extension-on-centos-5-with-latest-icu-data/
to install php intl.

Please advise.

Thank you,
Adrian

Comment: Using the repo is not sufficient for you ? ```yum install icu``` (http://serverfault.com/questions/210889/installing-enabling-php-pecl-intl-extension-on-centos-5)

Comment: For some reason yum was telling me that the ICU package is not available.

Comment: That is because I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some diligent browsing I found this post:
[Can't get to install 'intl' extension for php on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727736/cant-get-to-install-intl-extension-for-php-on-debian)

Using:
sudo apt-get install php5-intl

I managed to install the ICU libary and the intl extension for php, no need to do anything else although I am curios why installing it as above did not work. I know my way around nix operating systems but I am not an expert.