# When installing php7.3-intl on debian docker gives error "has no installation candidate"

Tags: php, docker, debian, intl, php-7.3

I have a wordpress installation via docker-compose. It uses php7.3 (I checked for version). Now the problem is like this : A wp function uses Locale class -> need to enable php_intl(not found in php.ini) -> tried to install php7.3-intl -> Gives error

```
Package php7.3-intl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'php7.3-intl' has no installation candidate
```

I tried the solutions as mentioned in these sites: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-debian-9-debian-8/, https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.2, and [Can't get to install 'intl' extension for php on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727736/cant-get-to-install-intl-extension-for-php-on-debian). Finally ended with this error from the last link:

```
/tmp/pear/temp/intl/intl_error.h:24:10: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried `nano /tmp/pear/temp/intl/intl_error.h` but the path doesn't exist. Also, When asked  `Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT]` i just hit enter.

What do I do next, or is there a better way to solve my original problem ?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and I solved running this command inside the container:

```
docker-php-ext-install intl
```

if you have Debian, install **libicu-dev** using:
`apt install libicu-dev`

(thx @Jose Fanjul)

Comment: WIth debian install previous `apt-get install libicu-dev`